# How can I use plus sign in camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have faced a problem.
I use camel When I send a url to other system through proxy-server
I encoded url using `URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8")` in java
so I saw plus sign(+) convert to "%2B"
But When I used `org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.normalizeUri()` method
, that returned "%2B" to space(" ").

Not only this, "?", "=", "&" sign ouccured same problem.
Is it camel's bug ? if so 
Could you tell me How to fix it?.

same problem

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8056?jql=project%20%3D%20CAMEL%20AND%20text%20~%20plus

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your URL?

Comment: @LHCHIN I'm not able to provide you entirely same URL cause Security but similar url show you. `http://test.com/inDs?msg=show+me+the+money`

Comment: I tested your sample URL and it worked fine. Could you also post your sample code and which version of camel-core you are using, mine is 2.24.1.

Comment: @LHCHIN Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Did you think is it version problem? Did you test Encoded URL like `http://test.com/inDs?msg=show%2Bme%2Bthe%2money`..

Comment: @LHCHIN I think `org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.normalizeUri()` method has a problem about encoding thus I want to see method logic . 
How can I see that?

Comment: YES! I just used `org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.normalizeUri()` for `http://test.com/inDs?msg=show%2Bme%2Bthe%2Bmoney` and it returned `http://test.com/inDs?msg=show+me+the+money`.

Comment: @LHCHIN Thank you. I solve the problem use RAW() method

Comment: Congratulations!